# How to render the main layout and partials with koa-views + handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, koa

This is my views folder structure:

```
- views
  - layouts
      layout.hbs
  - partials
      part.hbs
  home.hbs
```

I'm rendering the template width:

```
app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', {
  extension: 'hbs',
  map: { hbs: 'handlebars' }
}));

router.get('/', async (ctx) => {
  await ctx.render('home', {
    Name: 'Iris',
    Type: 'Web',
    Path: '/'
  });
});
```

What I want is to define the main layout file and the partials folder, just like if it was in `express-handlebars`. Really there's no way to achieve this with `koa-views` and pure `handlebars`?

I have to use `koa-hbs` or `koa-handlebars`? But they using soon deprecated features (and Handlebars v2.0.0, v3.0.0):

```
koa deprecated Support for generators will been removed in v3.
See the documentation for examples of how to convert old middleware
https://github.com/koajs/koa/tree/v2.x#old-signature-middleware-v1x app.js:45:5
```

**EDIT:**

Seems like `koa-hbs` and `koa-handlebars` plugins not compatible with `koa v2`. So there's no way to use `koa v2`, `partials` and `layouts` rendered with `handlebars` at the moment? :( Without those (define `layouts`, `partials`) `handlebars` are useless. So still stucked with `express`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

koa-hbs is really just using handlebars `.registerPartial` under the hood.

As basic as possible:

```
var handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    fs = require('fs')

handlebars.registerPartial(
    'defaultLayout',
    fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/layouts/default.html', 'utf8')
)

// then continue with loading the application...
```

But you probably want the convenience of it just loading your entire partials folder on startup though.

1. Create a Promise, and have a function execute that reads through your partials folder, and registers each partial via `handlebars.registerPartial`. It should resolve the Promise when they are all registered.
2. Create a middleware async that waits for that Promise to be resolved, so your app doesn't render any views before those partials are registered

Here's an example that I use:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    handlebars = require('handlebars'),
    glob = require('glob'), // for convenience, npm install glob
    path = require('path')

function readAsPromise (path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            resolve({path: path, data: data})
        })
    })
}

function registerPartial (partial) {
    var partialName = path.basename(partial.path, '.hbs')

    handlebars.registerPartial(partialName, partial.data)
}

var loadPartials = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    glob('./views/partials/*.hbs', function (err, files) {
        Promise.all(files.map(readAsPromise)).then(function (partials) {
            partials.forEach(registerPartial)
            resolve()
        })
    })

})
```

Now the question is which version of Koa are you using

```
// koa 1

app.use(function* (next) {
    yield loadPartials
    yield next
})

// latest koa

app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  await loadPartials
})
```

Now just use partials in handlebars as normal. This works fine with koa-views which will require the same instance of handlebars

Comment: Thank You for your answer! I use `koa v2`.